# Tizen error in Unity: "Default profile path is not set in the Tizen CLI configuration"

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, tizen

I want to build a Tizen in Inity, but I got an error message.

> 'profiles path in tizen CLI configuration does not exist.'

And the build fails. The '.tizen-cli-config' file was created on my desktop.

I've set the re path, but received the same error message.

[image]

Comment: Did you follow step 3 described in following link ?

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/tizen-setup.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you confirm that you have created certificate and link that certificate in your unity project.

[For How to create certificate refer this](https://gamedevtodied.blogspot.in/2015/09/unity3d-tizen-sdk-unityexception.html)

And also confirm you have enabled developer mode in device
[Check this](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/tizen-setup.html)

And also confirm that your unity project path does not have any special character. It will be fail if any folder(Directory) name have special character.

Comment: thanks I solved the problem Changing the version of Unity. Anyway, thank you kindly answered.

Answer (score 0):

Read the Tizen set up documentation from unity docs.
Link : -[Unity Documentation for Tizen Set Up](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/tizen-setup.html)